# error with pyspark foreachPartition() code restructuring

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks, partition

My code structure is as follows:

```
class SampleClass
    def __init__(self, spark):
        df = (spark.read.table("sampletable").repartition(100))

        def func1(partition):
            print(partition.getPartitionId)
            print(partition.count())
            // some operations on partition DF

        df.rdd.foreachPartition(func1)

def main():
    s = SampleClass()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I get an error like:

```
Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

how can i fix this calling structure? I am using databricks runtime 7.3LTS and spark 3.0.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to achieve - usually the `foreachPartition` is used for very specific reason

Comment: this 'some operations on partition DF' part of code contains several heavy aggregations, so I want to work with smaller batches of code to help with OOM issues.

Comment: Using RDDs, especially in Python, will make your code much slower and potentially requiring more memory, compared to using PySpark APIs, where optimizer will take care for efficient code generation, memory layout optimization, etc.

Comment: what other pyspark APIs do you recommend or other perf strategies to above?

Comment: It's really hard to tell which API you can use without knowing the logic you're looking for. `some operations on partition DF` is obviously unclear :)